# Is there a way to show convergence of DQN other than by eye observation?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn

I made a DQN model and plot its reward curve. You can see intuitively that the curve already converged since its reward value now just oscillates. How can I show confidence that my DQN already reached its optimal other than by just showing the curve? Are there any way to validate that it is already optimized?